# Qt5: Call main-application functions from within a plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, qt5

I am currently messing around with plugins in Qt5 (QPlugin). More specifically I have been looking into this example:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-echoplugin-example.html

There they create an abstract interface class to access functions in the plugin. Now here comes the question: Does this work the other way around?

Say I do stuff in my plugin and want to print some results to a GUI which lives in the main application. Can I call GUI functions from within the plugin? Or is there another way to achieve this kind of communication from plugin to application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messed a bit around and...

Answer was, to simply send the Main GUI's pointer as parameter of one of the interface functions and storing that pointer in the plugin class. That way, you can access the GUI (and other classes in the main application) from within the plugin.